# Using a generic model in Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, generics, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6

Here's a part of my database:

```
public abstract class LmData
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public LmDataType Type { get; set; }
}

[Table("ListLmDatas")]
public class ListLmData<T> : LmData where T : LmData
{
    public virtual List<T> Value { get; set; }
    public ListLmData()
    {
        Type = LmDataType.List;
    }
}
```

As you see, I'm trying to use a generic model in my database (which inherits from LmData).
I have added this and updated the database (and EF doesn't seem to complain).

Another model has a reference to the generic model(ListLmData), referenced as shown below (simplified):

```
public class WpSite
{
    public virtual ListLmData<StringLmData> Urls { get; set; }
}
```

However running the following code:

```
WpSite wp = new WpSite();
wp.Urls = new ListLmData<StringLmData>();
wp.Urls.Add(new StringLmData());
context.WpSites.Add(wp);
context.SaveChanges();
```

results in a WpSite being added, but with the .Urls property being NULL.

Furthermore, when checking my database I see that there appears to be NO table named "**ListLmDatas**" which furthermore confuses me.

**Are generic models not supported in Entity Framework 6.1.1?**

On a side note, yes I haven't shown the model definition for "StringLmData" because it is irrelevant to the issue as far as I can see.

Answer (score 0):

Inheritance works, Generics does not.